# Sturm-Liouville Form (e.g. Bessel Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

> I am trying to convert the Bessel equation $$z^2u''+zu'+(k^2z^2-v^2)u=0,$$ into the Sturm-Liouville form.

Dividing by $z$ ($z\neq 0$), we yield $$zu''+u'+(k^2z-v^2z^{-1})u=0\implies (zu')'+(k^2z-v^2z^{-1})u=0.$$
Now I believe this is in Sturm-Liouville form, as it is of the form $$(p(z)u')'+(q(z)+\lambda r(z))u=0.$$
My question is, how do we know what values $q(z)$ and $r(z)$ correspond to?

Comment: You could perhaps do some kind of rescaling substitution to combine the $k^2$ and $v^2$ into a single eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then you'll have each of your functions $p,q,r$.

Comment: Are you able to show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter $v$ is something that comes from separation of variables in other variables. So it should be treated as fixed. Your parameter $k^2$ is typically the eigenvalue parameter associated with the Bessel equation. So $\lambda=k^2$. The Sturm-Liouville form for the Bessel equation for a fixed $v$ is
$$
    (zu')'+(-v^2/z+k^2z)u=0
$$
which matches your form

$$
    (pu')'+(q+\lambda r)u = 0, \\
      p(z)=z,\;\; q(z)=-v^2/z,\;\; r(z)=z^2,\;\; \lambda=k^2.
$$

Comment: The equation obtained from your SL condition is not the same as the bessel equation.

Comment: Differentiating wrt z we obtain $zu''+u'+((kz)^2-v^2))u=0$

Comment: @EduardoV.Kuri : Multiply my equation by $z$ and you get the standard Bessel form.