# Problem in expressing a Bessel equation as a Sturm Liouville equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

This is part of a textbook on differential equation. The author intends to express the Bessel equation as a Sturm Liouville equation.

> Bessel’s equation as a Sturm–Liouville equation. The Bessel function $J_{n}(x)$ with fixed integer $n\geq 0$ satisfies Bessel’s equation $x^{2}y''+xy'+(x^{2}-n^{2})y=0$ so we can write
> $${\tilde x}^{2}\ddot{J_{n}}(\tilde x)+\tilde x{\dot J}_{n}(\tilde x)+({\tilde x}^{2}-n^{2})J_{n}(\tilde x)=0$$
> where ${\dot J}_{n}={{dJ_{n}}\over{d\tilde x}}$ and ${\ddot J}_{n}={{d^{2}J_{n}}\over{d{\tilde x}^{2}}}$. we set $\tilde x=kx$ then $x={{\tilde x}\over{k}}$ and by the chain rule, ${\dot J}_{n}={{dJ_{n}}\over{d\tilde x}}={{dJ_{n}}\over{dx}}/k={{{J_{n}}'}\over{k}}$ and ${\ddot J}_{n}={{{J_{n}}''}\over{k^{2}}}$. In the first two terms of Bessel’s equation, $k^{2}$and $k$ drop out and we obtain
> $$x^{2}{J_{n}}''(kx)+x{J_{n}}'(kx)+(k^{2}x^{2}-n^{2})J_{n}(kx)=0$$
> Dividing by $x$ and using  ${\left({x{J_{n}}'(kx)}\right)}'=x{J_{n}}''(kx)+{J_{n}}'(kx)$ gives the Sturm–Liouville equation:
> $${\left[{x{J_{n}}'(kx)}\right]}'+\left({-{{n^{2}}\over{x}}+\lambda x}\right)J_{n}(kx)=0$$
> where $\lambda=k^{2}$. this is a Sturm–Liouville equation $${\left[{p(x)y'}\right]}'+\left({q(x)+\lambda r(x)}\right)y=0$$
> with $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=-{{n^{2}}\over{x}}$, $r(x)=x$ and parameter $\lambda=k^{2}$.

[advanced engineering mathematics 10th ed by Erwin Kreyszig] I think there is a problem with relation
$$x^{2}{J_{n}}''(kx)+x{J_{n}}'(kx)+(k^{2}x^{2}-n^{2})J_{n}(kx)=0$$
In fact, according to the chain rule
$${\dot J}_{n}(\tilde x)={{dJ_{n}(\tilde x)}\over{d\tilde x}}={{dJ_{n}(\tilde x)}\over{dx}}{{dx}\over{d\tilde x}}={{dJ_{n}(kx)}\over{dx}}\cdot{{1}\over{k}}={{{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'}\over{k}}$$
And in a similar way
$${\ddot J}_{n}(\tilde x)={{{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}''}\over{k^{2}}}$$
Therefore, by inserting these relations into Equation
$${\tilde x}^{2}\ddot{J_{n}}(\tilde x)+\tilde x{\dot J}_{n}(\tilde x)+({\tilde x}^{2}-n^{2})J_{n}(\tilde x)=0$$
we get
$$x^{2}{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}''+x{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'+(k^{2}x^{2}-n^{2})J_{n}(kx)=0$$
relation ${\left({x{J_{n}}'(kx)}\right)}'=x{J_{n}}''(kx)+{J_{n}}'(kx)$ is also wrong. The correct form of this equation is $${\left[{x{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'}\right]}'=x{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}''+{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'$$
Using this relation and dividing by $x$, we get
$${\left[{x{\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'}\right]}'+\left({-{{n^{2}}\over{x}}+\lambda x}\right)J_{n}(kx)=0$$
In summary, in my opinion, ${\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'$ should be used instead of ${J_{n}}'(kx)$ Because these two expressions are not the same. indeed ${\left[{J_{n}(kx)}\right]}'=k{J_{n}}'(kx)$.
This image shows the section from the book along with the corrections I made
What you think? Am I right or is the book written correctly?
[image]

Comment: What is the role of $k$? It looks like at the end the change is undone in some way? Or in other words, what makes the case of a general $k$ different from the case $k=1$?

Comment: It was a good question. We have proved that the function $J_{n}(kx)$ applies to Sturm Liouville's differential equation. Now we have to show that this function satisfies two conditions $$\left\{{\matrix{
{k_{1}y(a)+k_{2}y'(a)=0}\cr
{l_{1}y(b)+l_{2}y'(b)=0}\cr
}}\right.$$ so that we can conclude that functions $J_{n}(kx)$ are orthogonal on the interval $\left[{a,b}\right]$. here $a=0$ and since $p(x)=x$ is zero at $x=0$ so first condition $k_{1}y(a)+k_{2}y'(a)=0$ canbe dropped and we need to find a $b$ that satisfies the second condition

Comment: . For this purpose, we assume $b=R$ and $k=k_{nm}={{\alpha_{nm}}\over{R}}$ where $\alpha_{nm}$ is the $m$th root of the $n$th Bessel function so that $J_{n}(k_{nm}R)=J_{n}({{\alpha_{nm}}\over{R}}R)=J_{n}(\alpha_{nm})=0$.

Comment: Therefore, function $J_{n}(k_{nm}x)$ applies in the second condition with $l_{1}=1$ and $l_{2}=0$ and $b=R$. Therefore, we concluded that the function $J_{n}(k_{nm}x)$ with $k_{nm}={{\alpha_{nm}}\over{R}}$ is orthogonal on $\left[{0,R}\right]$.

Comment: Here we used the orthogonality theorem of eigenfunctions of Sturm Liouville problem. According to this theorem, Eigenfunctions of Sturm–Liouville Problems are orthogonal. For example in this case $$\int\limits_{0}^{R}{xJ_{n}(k_{n,m}}x)J_{n}(k_{n,j}x)dx=0$$ provided that $m\ne j$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sturm-Liouville Form (e.g. Bessel Equation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978456/sturm-liouville-form-e-g-bessel-equation)

Answer (score 1):

I think the author was basically correct.
For typesetting convenience let $u= \overline x$.  Consider the author's change of variables  in which $u= kx$. Then $ u^2\frac{d^2}{du^2} = k^2 \frac{d^2}{k^2  d^2 x}$. Note that the powers of $k$ cancel. Ditto for $ u\frac{d}{du}$.  So the Bessel equation looks essentially the same in either set of letters. The only exception to such cancellation of powers is the  undifferentiated last term $ (u^2- n^2) J(u)$ which becomes $(k^2 x^2 -n^2) J_n(kx)$. (This is the only term in the Bessel equation that acquires an occurrence of $k^2$ under this substitution.)

To rearrange the Bessel equation to the Sturm-Liouville format it might have been cleaner if the author had  done that step first, using only the $u$ variable.
Start with  the Bessel equation
$ u^2 J''(u) + \ldots$; then divide by $u$; then write $(uJ'(u))'= uJ''+ J'$ etc. At the very end replace $u=kx$.